# inotify/max_user_watches value resets on reboot; how to change it permanently?

Tags: inotify

Some software that I'm using needs a higher-than-default value in `/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`. I can modify this value with a text editor or from the terminal, and for a little while, everything is fine. However, after *restarting* my computer (not just logging out and in again, which works fine), the value has reset to 8192.

Why does this happen, and how can I make the change permanent?

Comment: P.S. I'm *guessing* that the behaviour I'm observing happens by default on Ubuntu, but I don't *know* that's true - I've only tested on my own machine. If I'm wrong, then this will end up being a [Hail-Mary question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255426/are-hail-mary-questions-on-topic-for-stack-overflow) that is only answerable if somebody can guess what odd thing I might've done or installed that would cause the `max_user_watches` value to reset to 8192 on reboot. My apologies if that is the case!

Answer (score 10):

On Ubuntu 16.04 the following worked for me...

```
echo "fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo sysctl -p
```

where 524288 is the higher-than-default number that I'm using. The second command is to make it take effect without rebooting.

Also, here is a link to a similar question with some good answers, in particular see the second answer from user3086182 which helped me.

[kernel-inotify-watch-limit-reached](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13751/kernel-inotify-watch-limit-reached)

Answer (score 8):

From: `/usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-default.conf`:

> To override settings in this file, create a local file in /etc (e.g. /etc/sysctl.d/90-override.conf), and put any assignments there.

So create the file: `nano /etc/sysctl.d/90-override.conf`.
And populate it with: `fs.inotify.max_user_watches=65536`.

This will now be used when you restart your server to populate: `/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`

There is no need therefore to edit `/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`. Once you've followed the above you can restart your server for the new setting to take affect.

Comment: Like a man! I think it's the best way.

Comment: Accepted answer for me